# Cascade Update & Delete

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cascade

I have a large database and I didn't add cascade on update/delete.

Can we do it with T-SQL without deleting and then recreating all the FK objects?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: [SQL Script to alter ALL Foreign Keys to add ON DELETE CASCADE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/871124/1175077)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should drop and recreate foreign keys.
this is the only way.
but you can use `sys.foreign_keys` and `sys.foreign_key_columns` to get the FK name and columns.
then you can write a loop to fetch names and columns and drop an recreate it with cascade option in every time loop executed.