# PostgreSQL add 'on delete cascade' to all foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I am looking for a way to add `on delete cascade` to all foreign keys in my PostgreSQL database (preferably limitable to a schema). I have found a script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868620/sql-script-to-alter-all-foreign-keys-to-add-on-delete-cascade), but it doesn't seem to work for PostgreSQL. The solution doesn't have to use a script, a GUI tool would also be fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended and supported way to do this is to add new constraints with the same definition and `ON DELETE CASCADE`, then drop the original constraints.

If you are ready to risk breaking your database with a catalog modification, and you trust a random SQL statement from the internet, you could try

```
WITH tables(oid) AS (
   UPDATE pg_constraint
   SET confdeltype = 'c'
   WHERE contype = 'f'
     AND confdeltype <> 'c'
     AND connamespace = 'myschema'::regnamespace
   RETURNING confrelid
)
UPDATE pg_trigger
SET tgfoid = '"RI_FKey_cascade_del"()'::regprocedure
FROM tables
WHERE tables.oid = pg_trigger.tgrelid
  AND tgtype = 9;
```

Test well before using!

Answer (score 0):

Short of altering the database catalogue, this function should do the trick in a way that is a little less scary.

```sql
create function "UpdateAllForeignKeys"(on_delete varchar)
returns void
language plpgsql
as
    $$
declare
    rec record;
    drop_statement varchar;
    add_statement varchar;
begin
for rec in
    select
        tc.table_schema,
        tc.constraint_name,
        tc.table_name,
        kcu.column_name,
        ccu.table_schema as foreign_table_schema,
        ccu.table_name as foreign_table_name,
        ccu.column_name as foreign_column_name
    from information_schema.table_constraints as tc
    join information_schema.key_column_usage as kcu
        on tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
        and tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
    join information_schema.constraint_column_usage as ccu
        on ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
        where tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
        and tc.table_schema = 'my_schema'
        and ccu.table_schema = 'my_foreign_schema'
    LOOP
        execute 'alter table only ' || rec.table_schema || '.' || rec.table_name || ' drop constraint ' || rec.constraint_name || ';';
        execute 'alter table only ' || rec.table_schema || '.' || rec.table_name || ' add constraint ' || rec.constraint_name || ' foreign key (' || rec.column_name || ') references ' || rec.foreign_table_schema || '.' || rec.foreign_table_name || ' (' || rec.foreign_column_name || ') on delete ' || on_delete || ';';
    end loop;
end;
$$;

select "UpdateAllForeignKeys"('cascade');
```